# jasmine testing promises unknown error

Tags: javascript, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

When doing testing with jasmine + karma + phantomjs + es6-promises (npm lib),  found the following issue but I'm not finding what's going on. I wonder if someone can have a look and help identify the issue:

```
at formatError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/versioned/^3.7.0/formatError.js:20:10)
at Gulp.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/versioned/^3.7.0/log/events.js:41:15)
at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
at Gulp.emit (events.js:182:7)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (/Users/helder/www/coach-test/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:264:8)
at /Users/helder/www/coach-test/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:275:23
at finish (/Users/helder/www/coach-test/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:21:8)
at cb (/Users/helder/www/coach-test/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:29:3)
at removeAllListeners (/Users/helder/www/coach-test/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:379:7)
at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/helder/www/coach-test/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:390:9)
at Server.g (events.js:273:16)
at emitNone (events.js:85:20)
at Server.emit (events.js:179:7)
at emitCloseNT (net.js:1514:8)
at nextTickCallbackWith1Arg (node.js:464:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:386:17)
```

I've got the following object, with a method that does a XHR request:

```
function List (params) {
    this.init(params);
}

List.prototype = {
    init: function (params) {
       // ....
    },

    requestData: function (url) {

        var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.open("GET", url, true);

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function (ev) {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        console.log(xhr.responseText);
                        resolve(xhr.responseText);
                    } else {
                        reject(Error(xhr.statusText));
                    }
                }
            };

            xhr.send(null);

        });

        return promise;

    }

};

module.exports = List;
```

The jasmine test spec:

```
describe("List generator", function () {

    var request = null;
    var list = new List({ autoload: false });

    beforeEach(function (done) {

        jasmine.Ajax.install();

        list.requestData(config.api).then(function () {
            done();
        });

        request = jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent();
        expect(request.url).toBe(config.api);
        expect(request.method).toBe('GET');

    });

});
```